# Why is my app's spring boot app interfering with another spring boot app from Adobe's s3mock test framework

Tags: spring, spring-boot, amazon-s3, spock

The context is I am using s3mock-junit5 for mocking s3 using groovy's Spock framework

```
testImplementation group: 'com.adobe.testing', name: 's3mock-junit5', version: '2.4.10'
```

I had to write a groovy's custom Extension because s3mock does work with junit4 and 5 out of the box but not with Spock.

```
package com.myapp.test.utils
...
class S3MockTestExtension extends S3MockStarter implements IAnnotationDrivenExtension<S3MockTest> {
```

Eventually the s3mock library runs a spring boot app (to mock the s3 behavior)

```
    final ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx =
    new SpringApplicationBuilder(S3MockApplication.class)
        .properties(translateLegacyProperties(defaults))
        .properties(translateLegacyProperties(properties))
        .bannerMode(bannerMode)
        .run(args);
```

The problem I have is that it tries to create beans that my app uses (the data source and amazon's SdkClient):

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)
    ... 97 more
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
```

Why does it do that? The library spring boot Application class has a `@ComponentScan` annotation, but the base package is way different from my app's package.

```
package com.adobe.testing.s3mock;
...
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class},
    excludeName = {"org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.security.servlet."
        + "ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration"})
@ComponentScan
public class S3MockApplication {
```

Comment: That sounds like a pretty complex mix of technologies. I would guess that you could get better help (or any help at all), if you would prepare an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on GitHub for everyone to be able to reproduce your problem.

Comment: You might want to give this extension a try https://github.com/xvik/spock-junit5 then maybe you don't need a custom extension.